# Could not load /vercel/path0/vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.es.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, vercel, inertiajs

Hello i am facing the issue trying to deploy my Laravel, Inertia, Vite, Vue app on vercel.

i have no error testing my app in my localhost, everythinh works...

Vercel insted print this error:

[vite:load-fallback] Could not load /vercel/path0/vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.es.js (imported by resources/js/app.js): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vercel/path0/vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.es.js'
error during build:
Error: Could not load /vercel/path0/vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.es.js (imported by resources/js/app.js): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vercel/path0/vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.es.js'
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

This is my vite.config.js file:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.js"],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                base: null,
                includeAbsolute: false,
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ziggy: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.es.js"
            ),
        },
    },
});
```

and this is my app.js file:

```
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import MainLayout from "@/Layouts/Mainlayout.vue";
import { ZiggyVue } from "ziggy";

createInertiaApp({
    progress: {
        // The delay after which the progress bar will appear, in milliseconds...
        delay: 250,

        // The color of the progress bar...
        color: "#29d",

        // Whether to include the default NProgress styles...
        includeCSS: true,

        // Whether the NProgress spinner will be shown...
        showSpinner: false,
    },
    resolve: (name) => {
        const pages = import.meta.glob("./Pages/**/*.vue", { eager: true });
        let page = pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`];
        page.default.layout = page.default.layout || MainLayout;
        return page;
    },
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue)
            .mount(el);
    },
});
```

how can i fix with vercel??
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Vercel, but Heroku. I fixed this by reversing the Php and Node Buildpacks in Heroku settings. Php needs to be ran first, THEN Nodjs(composer needs to be installed first).

You would have to adapt this for other host sites.